# Get the list of all selected check boxes with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, v-model

How can I get a list of all *check boxes* that I selected with Vue?
This is my HTML which works and shows me a list of my products with a checkbox.

```
<li v-for="(product, index) in products">
    <input :id="product.slug" :value="product.id" name="product" type="checkbox" />
    <label :for="product.slug"><span></span></label>
</li>
```

What I want is that when I click on a button, it fetches all check boxes that I selected. And give me all the values.
But I can't figure out how to do it, because it'll break when I even try to add a `v-model` to the checkbox.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just bind every checkbox `value` with a product and the `v-model` to the array `checkedProducts`

```
<li v-for="(product, index) in products">
    <input :id="product.slug" :value="product" name="product" type="checkbox" v-model="checkedProducts" />
    <label :for="product.slug"><span></span></label>
</li>

...
data(){
 return{
   ...
    checkedProducts:[]
   ....
   }
 }
```