# add checkboxs values to data array in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, nuxt.js, v-model

I am using nuxt `v2.15`

Those are my checkboxes:

```html
<div v-for="category in categories" v-bind:key="category.id" class="ml-4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" @change="search()" v-model="form.categories" :id="`category`+category.id" :value="category.id">
  <label :for="`category`+category.id">{{ category.title }}</label>
</div>
```

When I check one of them, `form.categories` becomes `true`! The value of the checkbox is not added to the `form.categories` array.

It should store values of checkboxes (`category.id`) in `form.categories` but instead it toggles `form.categories` to `true` and `false` state.

How can I store checkbox values inside `form.categories`?

PS: I have a project with older version of Nuxt and this is working fine! But in the new project this is not working. Is it because of a newer version?

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52152854/8172857

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim its not working ! i want to send html checkbox array ! why its so hard ? why it stop working in new project ?! :| :(

Comment: This is *98%* not coming from the newer version. Can you show both files, with the older and newer version please?

Comment: i copied the code from old project ! the code is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve it by writing a function to add category.id into form.categories :

```
addCategory (id) {
  if(!this.form.categories.includes(id))
     this.form.categories.push(id);
  else
     this.form.categories.splice(this.form.categories.indexOf(id), 1);
  this.search()
```

}

i call it in checkbox @change